# Call method of an object in an array

Tags: ruby

When trying to call the closePrice method on the stock object, nothing is being printed out. However, the currently commented code works. How can I iterate through the StockList array and call the closePrice method of my Stock objects?

```
class Stock
    attr_reader :date, :open, :high, :low, :close, :adjClose, :volume
    def initialize(date, open, high, low, close, adjClose, volume)
        @date = date
        @open = open
        @high = high
        @low = low
        @close = close
        @adjClose = adjClose
        @volume = volume
    end

    def closePrice
        "Close price: #{@close}"
    end
end

class StockList < Array

    def initialize()
        @stockList = []
    end

    def addStock(stock)
        @stockList.push(stock)
    end

end

stocks = Array.new
stockList = StockList.new()


CSV.foreach(fileName) do |stock|
    entry = Stock.new(stock[0], stock[1], stock[2], stock[3], stock[4], stock[5], stock[6])
    stocks.push(entry)

    stockList.addStock(entry)
end

# stocks.each do |stock|
#     puts stock.closePrice
# end

stockList.each do |stock|
    puts stock.closePrice
end
```

Could it be that there are missing links? Only beginning with Ruby. Thanks.

Comment: This code should work. One thing to note is Ruby strongly encourages you to name variables and method names all lower-case like `close_price`. Capitals are reserved for constants and class/module names. Additionally that `new` method takes an absurd number of arguments. You should steer towards taking in a hash that has all the associated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is in your implementation of `StockList`. You have extended the class array but are setting up a new instance variable `@stockList`. When you call `addStock` you are adding an instance to the `@stockList` variable. But when you call `each` on the `StockList` instance, it is not iterating over the `StockList`.

Conceivably, you could add a method `each` to `StockList` like:

`def each(&block)
  @stockList.each(&block)
end`

and it should work.

But really I would recommend rethinking your data structures. `StockList` should really not extend `Array`.

Comment: Thanks Rob, any suggestions as to how I should structure my data? The idea behind this was to have a ```List``` of stocks that I could add methods to.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with extending Array per-se, but in this case it doesn't add any functionality so it's kind of pointless. The difference between the `stocks` array and this StockList thing is basically zero.

Comment: I think having a `StockList` object is fine. I just wouldn't extend Array. It would just rely on the `@stockList` internal variable to maintain the data. And then you would add the appropriate methods and use as appropriate. If you really need a lot of iteration type methods (and I wonder whether you really do or not), you could either expose the `@stockList` variable (e.g. attr_reader :stockList) or if you wanted the methods on the object itself implement an `each` method and then [`include Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html)